# Change text according to date with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I would need a script that allows me to change the text of a paragraph according to the current date. For example, from June 1 to June 15, the text will be in the "first half of June" and from June 16 to June 30 there will be the text "second half of June", the same for the other months.

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the day from a date object (it's returned as an integer) and then change your text based on that:

```
var d = new Date()
var myNum = d.getDate()

if (myNum <= 15){
  //something
} else {
  //something else
}
```

Just replaced the commented area with `.innerHTML()` changing your text, or the jQuery equivalent if you so choose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I wanted to change text this way? For example: from June 15 to July 15 there will be "text 1", from July 16 to August 15 there will be "text 2" etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{month:'long'});
var partOfMonth =  dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{day:'numeric'}) < 16 ? 'first half' : 'second half';
var string = partOfMonth + ' of ' + month;
```

`string` is ultimately the variable that contains the string you want

It's also worth mentioning that while this usage of `.toLocaleDateString()` this isn't supported 100% everywhere, it does have [broad enough support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility) by modern browsers that I would consider it usable solution.

Comment: If you pass *undefined* as the language users will see the month in the default of their system rather than US English. `dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{day:'numeric'})`  is a long way of writing `dateObj.getDate()`. ;-)

Comment: OP wants to construct a string that consists of an English sentence fragment which will be inserted into previously written paragraph (which I assume is also in English), so I think it would make more sense to force `en-US` for the month rather than defaulting to the system language in this particular instance..... 
Fair point on  `dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{day:'numeric'}) === dateObj.getDate()` though :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var d = new Date();
var num = d.getDate();
var month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];

document.getElementById('dateText').innerHTML = num <= 15 ? 'first half of ' + month : 'second  half of ' + month;
```

```html
<p id="dateText">

</p>
```